# Combine multiple values into one field using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, aggregate-functions

This is a pretty simple question, as I'm still pretty new to MS SQL. I'm trying to figure out a way to combine all values except one into one single field using a case statement. To be more clear, using the Northwind Database as an example, I want to make a table that shows the number of orders placed to customers in Germany and the number of orders placed to customers from everywhere else.

This is the query I attempted:

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN A.Country = 'Germany' 
        THEN 'Germany'
    WHEN A.Country <> 'Germany'
        THEN 'Everywhere Else'
    END
AS ShipTo,
COUNT(OrderID)
    FROM Customers A
        INNER JOIN Orders B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
GROUP BY Country;
```

Of Course that brings up a table like this in which every country appears separately by aliased as 'Everywhere Else'.

```
Everywhere Else 22
Everywhere Else 122
Everywhere Else 28
Everywhere Else 83
Germany 122
Everywhere Else 18
Everywhere Else 28
Everywhere Else 37
Everywhere Else 16
Everywhere Else 40
Everywhere Else 56
Everywhere Else 7
Everywhere Else 30
Everywhere Else 19
Everywhere Else 6
Everywhere Else 77
```

I would like all "Everywhere Else" fields combined into one. I know that's possible cuz I've done something similar before, I just can't remember how.

Comment: Then don't `GROUP BY Country`, `GROUP BY` your `CASE` **expression** (it is not a statement). If you `GROUP BY Country` you are *explicitly* asking for one row per distinct value of `Country`.

Comment: Or consider a CROSS APPLY so you don't have to repeat the CASE

Comment: this article can be useful for you https://learnsql.com/blog/group-by-case-when/

Comment: @ThomA thank you, that's a very simple solution. But in SQL Server I cannot group by an alias. Do I put the entire case statement starting with CASE and ending with END after GROUP BY?

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on my comment.

```
SELECT C.ShipTo
      ,count(OrderID)
 FROM  Customers A
 JOIN Orders B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
 Cross Apply ( values (CASE WHEN A.Country = 'Germany' THEN 'Germany'        
                            ELSE 'Everywhere Else'  
                       END ) 
             ) C(ShipTo)
GROUP BY C.ShipTo;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Cross apply is new to me, I'll play around with it tomorrow!

Comment: @LibrarianMN The nice thing about CROSS APPLY and/or OUTER APPLY is that they allow you to stack and reuse derived values.